# pyqt5 custom dialog input popup within main window

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I need to generate a custom popup input window triggered by clicking a `QPushButton` in my app (via `clicked`). It needs to get several inputs from the user of different types and then return them to the calling function inside the main window app. I have found built in functions such as `QInputDialog` that can do this for single specific inputs, but I can't figure out how to do this in the case of a popup that asks for several inputs of different types at once (preferably in a window designed in Qt Designer). Does anyone know how to do this?

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5 import uic

path = os.path.dirname(__file__) #uic paths from itself, not the active dir, so path needed
qtCreatorFile = "NAME.ui" #Ui file name, from QtDesigner

Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(path + qtCreatorFile) #process through pyuic

class MyApp(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow): #gui class
    def __init__(self):
        #Set up the gui via Qt
        super(MyApp, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.add_button.clicked.connect(self.add_row) #add_button is QPushButton

    def add_row(self):
        data1, data2, data3 = #popup form to get data (types are not the same)
        #do stuff with data
        pass

#start app 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv) #instantiate a QtGui (holder for the app)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no single solution but I will give you a guide to do what you want.

If you want to get a widget with the behavior of QInputDialog you must first choose the right template, in this case a good option is Dialog with Buttons Bottom or Dialog with Buttons Right, add the components you want, position it, etc.

[image]

Then as you show your code you create a class that inherits from QDialog and then create a method where you get the results but to do so do not use `show()` but `exec_()`

```
path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
qtCreatorFile = "some_dialog.ui"

Ui_Dialog, _ = uic.loadUiType(os.path.join(path,qtCreatorFile))

class CustomDialog(QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomDialog, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        # set initials values to widgets

    def getResults(self):
        if self.exec_() == QDialog.Accepted:
            # get all values
            val = self.some_widget.some_function()
            val2 = self.some_widget2.some_another_function()
            return val1, val2, ...
        else:
            return None
```

And then use it in your function:

```
class MyApp(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow): #gui class
    def __init__(self):
        #Set up the gui via Qt
        super(MyApp, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.add_button.clicked.connect(self.add_row) #add_button is QPushButton

    def add_row(self):
        w = CustomDialog()
        values = w.getResults()
        if values:
            data1, data2, data3 = values
```

Comment: Great solution, although you should mention that you need to `connect()` `accept` and `reject` to whatever buttons you put in the UI or you won't have anything for the `if values:` to check.